# How to use join feature on one table only in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table like below:

[image: data we have]

I want to categorize number of "type" column by month and one more column which shows the number of times they are repeated .(we need is 12 x number of types ( here we have three types ( 1,2,4)). I want for my result to be like below:

[image: the result we need]

I need the records even if there is no record for the month (the green 0 in the picture)

Do I need to use join command on the same table twice?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: To the point of that meta post... My computer has images blocked but not the website. I can't see anything you're trying to do there.

Comment: What about there are rows for march in tow different years?

Comment: Do you want to put the numbers for march into a single row for **all years**?

Comment: yeah the year is not important, I just need 12 months for every type, just categorizing by month

Comment: So, please edit your question by posting data as formatted text instead of images so that everyone can see and use your data. Also, please post what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `cross join` (to generate all possible combination of distinct types and months) and a `left join` with your table and finally aggregate to get the required counts.

```
select m.month,
    x.type,
    count(t.type)
from (
    select to_char(add_months(sysdate, level), 'Mon') as month
    from dual connect by level <= 12
    ) m
cross join (
    select distinct type
    from your_table
    ) x
left join your_table t on m.month = to_char(t.session_date, 'Mon')
    and x.type = t.type
group by m.month,
    x.type
order by x.type, to_date(m.month, 'Mon');
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/KDTN22455)

Comment: thank you, but why I get "column ambiguously defined" error on third line? I even tried "t"."type" but same error

Comment: @andrew - Works perfectly fine for me. See this demo - http://rextester.com/KDTN22455

Comment: you're brilliant, thanks, rextester is very useful as well

Comment: how how can I add one more column as the name of "type" in the result, the name is on another table, do I need another another left join ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first generate the complete list of all type values. If you do not have a foreign key to a different table, you can it like this.

```
select distinct type
from the_table
```

You apparently want to put all numbers for a single month into one row regardless of the year, so you need another list of 12 rows to join against:

```
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 12;
```

Now these two can be put together and joined against your table:

```
with all_types as (
  select distinct type
  from the_table
), all_months (month_nr) as (
  select level
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
select at.type, am.month_nr, count(*)
from all_types at
  cross join all_months am
  left join the_table t 
         on t.type = at.type 
        and extract(month from t.session_date) = am.month_nr
group by at.type, am.month_nr
order by at.type, am.month_nr;
```

This will display the month as a number, if you need it as a text, use `to_char(to_date(am.month_nr, 'mm'), 'Mon') as month` instead of just `am.month_nr` in the select list of the final select.

Comment: thank you ever so much genius, but for the month when we have no records, it shows 1 instead of 0, weird to me , why?